# Self sizing specific UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, contentsize

I know how to make UITableViewCells self size in UITableView. The question is how to only a specific cell self size itself. I have four different custom UITableView Cells in my table and I want to make only one cell self size itself.

Comment: you can check your cell indexpath for example and if is row == 0, then return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know which rows that you want to implement the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for because when because when `heightForRowAt` is called, no cells are created yet so you can´t check the cell type ye that´s why you need to check the `indexPath.row` instead.

Something like this for example:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    return 100
case 1,2,3:
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
default:
    return 100
}
```

Comment: @uzairshahzad, np. You changed the accepted answer, why if I may ask.

Comment: Opps, sorry. That was by mistake, rectified it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which cell you need to return dinamicHeigth and in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` according

**Example code using row 0 as condition**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }

        return 88
    }
```

Comment: How do you know that OP want the first cell?

Comment: I use example code only @RashwanL that condition can be any